# JavaScript-Not able to change the font-size of an element in the iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, powerbi

I have an iframe generated by Power BI. I am not able to change the font size.

I have tried targeting it by span and div but in vain.

```
    <script>
 var span = document.getElementById("myFrame");
span.style.fontSize = "100px";

        </script>

    <iframe span id="myFrame"  width="500" height="150" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNjBlM2EyMWUtMmU1My00NzkyLWE1NTgtNDYyZDUzZTg5YmM3IiwidCI6IjNiZDI3ZWY4LThkMzgtNDY1Ni04NmQyLTVmMGQ5MGE3Mzk4MSIsImMiOjN9" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Have also tried this

```
<script>
function changeSize(){
    var frame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    var content = (frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow);
    content.body.style.fontSize = "200%";
}

changeSize();
 </script>
```

The iframe displays a number. And I would like to Increase the font-size of that number using JavaScript. So far I have no luck. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the iframe url has to be on the same domain that the parent window/tab uses

Comment: You have no JavaScript access to content inside an iframe that is loaded from a different domain; that's called Same Origin Policy.

Comment: You should be getting error messages on the Console in your browser's developer tools. Reading them and using them as the basis for a web search would have saved you from having to ask this question.

Answer (score -3):

why does your `<iframe>` has 'span' in it?

write it like this:

```
<iframe id="myFrame"  width="500" height="150" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNjBlM2EyMWUtMmU1My00NzkyLWE1NTgtNDYyZDUzZTg5YmM3IiwidCI6IjNiZDI3ZWY4LThkMzgtNDY1Ni04NmQyLTVmMGQ5MGE3Mzk4MSIsImMiOjN9" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

now you can use your js like you used before :

```
var span = document.getElementById("myFrame");
span.style.fontSize = "200%";
```

or

```
var span = document.getElementById("myFrame");
span.style.fontSize = "xx-large";
```

Comment: Setting the font size of an iframe element does nothing for the size of the text in the document loaded into that frame.

Comment: @shikhar I tried applying your solution but unfortunately it didn't work.